# Country flag, for "entire world"

Tags: design, user-centered-design, visual-design, graphic-design

I was wondering if there was a "country flag", for the entire world.

(Even if you couldn't user it, for "space wars").

Thanks..

NOTE: I was thinking, of a flag, with a single color: all black.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a trivia question, not a User Experience one. What UX problem are you trying to solve with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several contenders - [Wikipedia seems to have most of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Earth)

Comment: some nice ones there :)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that an image of a globe (like these emojis -  ) would be recognizable as a *world flag*.

Answer (score 2):

See [Flag of Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Earth) and [Flag of the United Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_Nations).

> The most widely recognized flags associated with Earth are the Earth Day flag and the United Nations flag.